# Opening a port on HDInsight cluster on Azure

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I have a microsoft Azure HDInsight cluster.

On the node I am rdp'ing and starting an application that binds to port 8080. I would like to be able to connect to this application from outside the cluster.

I have my cluster connection string (https://xxxxx.azurehdinsight.net)  however when I try to connect to it I am timing out.

I believe this is due to the fact that I have not opened port 8080 to public. How can I do this as under the cluster I only have Hadoop Services and username....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point in time, we don't allow you to control / open additional network ports on an HDInsight cluster.

You can deploy an HDInsight cluster into an Azure Virtual network if you'd like to have another machine in Azure to have access to all of the ports/nodes on the cluster.  We've documented how to deploy into a vnet in this [article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-provision-clusters/).

Comment: I installed my app on an edge node, but still not able to access the application on port 8080. Also added this to the edge node template:-

"httpEndpoints": [{  
                "subDomainSuffix": "suf",  
                "destinationPort": 8080,  
                "accessModes": ["WebPage"]  
            }],

Comment: Hi Matt. Have you started allowing opening ports in HDInsight?

Comment: Hi, why is this restriction still in place 4.5 years later?

Comment: I have an edge node which is running airflow on that, how to access that?